# Create a single PHP class for an animal Bear

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way of a single CLASS named "Bear" to be able to:

- Eat honey every 2 hours and remember when they last had honey.
- Decide if they need to sleep.

I want to know is there a way of doing this without hard coding the array times and rather than using an else statement to decide if the bear needs to sleep would a separate function be better and cleaner?

```
class Bear

{

protected $name;
protected $currentTime;


public function setName($name)
{
   $this->name = $name;
}

public function getName()
{
   return $this->name;
}

public function showLastFeedtime()
{
   $lastFed = strtotime('-2 hour', strtotime($this->currentTime));

   $newdate = date('H:i', $lastFed);

   echo $this->name." last ate at ".$newdate."<br/><br/>";   
}

public function checkFeedingTime($checkHours = array())
{
   if(in_array($this->currentTime,$checkHours))
{
echo "It's ".$this->name."'s feeding time </br>";
echo "The time ".$this->currentTime. " is the time and I'm eating 
honey at right now. </br></br>";

echo "These are the times I eat</br>";

foreach($checkHours as $feedingTimes)
{
   echo $feedingTimes."</br>";    
}

echo "<hr>";

}
else
{
  //DECIDE IF THE BEAR NEEDS TO SLEEP
  echo "Barney is having a snooze";
}

}

public function getTime($currentTime)
{
   $this->currentTime = $currentTime;
}

public function setTime()
{
   return $this->currentTime;
}

}

//new instance of barney
$barney = new Bear();

//set the bears name
$barney->setName('Barney');

//get the bears name
$bigBear = $barney->getName();

//page info
echo "<h1>".$bigBear."'s profile page </h1>";
echo "<hr>";
echo "I am a bear and my name is {$bigBear} <br/>";
echo "<hr>";

//the current time
$currentTime = date('H:i');

$barney->getTime($currentTime);

//last feeding time
$barney->showLastFeedtime();

//ARRAY TIMES-barney eats every 2 hours
$checkHours = 
array('00:00','02:00','04:00','06:00','08:00',
'10:00','12:00','14:00','16:00','18:00','20:00','22:00');

//call the feeding time function
$barney->checkFeedingTime($checkHours);
?>
```

Comment: You need a mechanism to keep up with the time/state.

Answer (score 2):

Some short class:

```
    <?php
// Ok, so we are in role of god and probably, we will want to create
// more animals than just bear, so we will prepare cheap interface for
// our creations
interface Animal {
    // we should be aware, if our lil beast is hungry
    public function isHungry(): bool;
    // and we should know, that we can feed it
    public function feed(): void;

    public function live(): void;

    public function isSleepy(): bool;

    public function sleep(): void;
}

class State {
    public $sleeping;
}

// Kay, now we can start with making our master beer
class Bear implements Animal {
    /**
     * He should have name
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * We would like to know, when our bearsir was eating last time
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $lastEatingTime;

    /**
     * @var int 
     */
    private $energy;

    /**
     * @var State
     */
    private $state;

    // construction of bear, cause we can
    public function __construct(string $name, \DateTime $lastEatingTime)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->lastEatingTime = $lastEatingTime;
        $this->energy = 100;
        $state = new State();
        $state->sleeping = false;
        $this->state = $state;
    }
    // something like when you ask bear whats his name
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    // something like you get new bear and you wanna rename him
    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }
    // we have inteligent bear, so we can ask him about the last time of feeding
    public function getLastEatingTime(): \DateTime
    {
        return $this->lastEatingTime;
    }
    // we can also force him to think he ate before one minute even if its not true
    public function setLastEatingTime(\DateTime $lastEatingTime): self
    {
        $this->lastEatingTime = $lastEatingTime;
        return $this;
    }
    // we can determine if he is hungry or not by comparing current time and last time he ate
    public function isHungry(): bool
    {
        $now = new \DateTime();
        return $now->diff($this->getLastEatingTime())->format('%h') >= 2;
    }
    // give him food
    public function feed(): void
    {
        $this->energy += 5;
        $this->setLastEatingTime(new \DateTime());
    }

    public function isSleepy(): bool 
    {
        return $this->energy < 20;
    }

    /**
     * we will give him some rest
     */
    public function sleep(): void
    {
        $this->state->sleeping = true;
        $this->energy += rand(5, 20)/10;
        if ($this->energy >= 100) {
            $this->wakeUp();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Hey, wake up bear!
     */
    public function wakeUp(): void
    {
        $this->state->sleeping = false;
    }

    /**
     * Makes one lifecycle of bear
     */
    public function live(): void
    {
        $this->energy -= 1;
        if ($this->state->sleeping) {
            $this->sleep();
            echo 'Im sleeping';
        } else {
            echo 'Im awake and ';
            if ($this->isSleepy()) {
                echo 'Im sleepy, so i go sleep';
                $this->sleep();
            } else {
                if ($this->isHungry()) {
                    echo 'Im hungry, so im gonna eat some honey';
                    $this->feed();
                } else {
                    echo 'im fine';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
// lets make life
class Life {
    public function live(Animal $animal)
    {
        // let life go on forever till some asteroid crashes our server
        while (true) {
            $animal->live();
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
}

$myBear = new Bear("Stanley", new \DateTime());
$life = new Life();
$life->live($myBear);
```

Comment: What did you do? Why does it work? Explain your answer

Comment: @Martin its kind of selfexplaining code v2.0.1 thanks to naming variables, classes, types and annotations

Comment: Errr, no; there's no such thing as "self explaining code", else it would not be called *code* and you would also not need comments. Comments are extremely useful; use comments and write some prose in your answer to explain what is going on. It's easy for you -- you wrote it.

Comment: @Martin I dont event know if it works, its written in notepad -_-, can we agree on 4 comments?

Comment: Explain what you ***changed*** from the OPs code and *WHY* this change works.

Comment: @Martin Didnt change anything, wrote new class

Comment: Nice code, but you missed the `Decide if they need to sleep` requirement. Specifically, OP asked about how to implement the `if`/`else` Vs. function.

Comment: @waterloomatt i’ve made just part of it, just for inspiration, there will be same principle with sleeping. But it was quite funny, I will try to impl it when i reach home

Comment: @waterloomatt key, what about now?